# Angular JS Ng-switch default state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really new to AngularJS but I wondered if anyone knew how to get a default ng-switch state working on the following plunkr, at the moment I can only get it to work on click, but if the user button is toggled then really the menu should show first time.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bdu1T29cYe6mhb6OAFI8?p=preview

Any ideas? ng-switch-default didn't seem to do the trick on the user component...

cheers

phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using two separate variables when they're just configuration strings. Use both the same and everything works fine.

http://plnkr.co/edit/C28EwkuufYKs9Ipi0sA5?p=preview